# Optimizing erase from the end of vector into resize

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, compiler-optimization

Is it legal and possible that the compiler optimizes this code:

```
std::vector<T> my_vec(10);
//some code
my_vec.erase(my_vec.begin()+5,my_vec.end());
```

into:

```
std::vector<T> my_vec(10);
//some code
my_vec.resize(5);
```

I am asking because I always read that `std::vector::resize` is preferable when erasing from the end over an `std::vector::erase`. However, I see that `std::vector::erase` is more readable.

Comment: Where do you see it's preferable, and what is the rationale?

Comment: I saw it in some SO answers as a side note.. I can not remember what is the reason or if the reason was even mentioned. Maybe I should ask first if it is really better :)

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: no, why do **you** think `erase` looks better?

Comment: Those two calls will almost certainly do the same thing - so whichever you prefer is whichever you prefer.

Comment: @Barry no, that's not the case.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi, well, here is my very strong advice to you. Do not go along with 'preferable'. Preference is subjective. Instead, **always** understand what is the technical reason behind it. And if you do, you do not have to answer questions like this - you already know the answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller. Opinion-based thing. I think erase will be understandable even for a non c++ programmer or even a very very beginner programmer.

Comment: @SergeyA thanks for advice. Yes you are true. I should first be sure that resize is better then asking this question.

Comment: Take a look at the generated assembly code. This will tell you exactly what the compiler does.

Comment: @orbitcowboy Yeah it will help in one direction of the proof. However, I am asking theoretically question about the possibility of it regarding to the standards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type requirements are different.

- `vector::resize` (the one-parameter version) doesn't demand `MoveAssignable` but does require `DefaultInsertable` and `MoveInsertable`, because it can also be used to grow the container.
- `vector::erase` is the reverse; it requires `MoveAssignable` but not the others, because it can be used to erase in the middle.
- `vector::pop_back` requires none of the above, but only pops off one element at a time, so you will have to call it multiple times.

There should be no perceivable performance difference in any sane implementation.

Comment: So helpful. Thanks

Comment: A reason to have `std::vector::shrink_by`, which matches `pop_back`.  I suspect a loop of `pop_back` might be less efficient than a `shrink_by` can be, but maybe not: what should happen if one of the destructors of the objects throws?

Comment: @Yakk UB, as usual. Using a throwing destructor with the standard library is UB.

Answer (score 1):

Is it legal and possible for such optimizations to happen? Yes. Nothing in the specification forbids converting one into the other. So it's legal for `erase` operations from the end of the `vector` to be implemented in terms of the guts of a shrinking `resize`.

Comment: Wait, where does `resize` specify reverse order?

Comment: @T.C.: Yeah, I found that strange too. It's defined in terms of a sequence of `pop_back` calls: "*If `sz <= size()`, equivalent to calling `pop_back()` `size() - sz` times.*"

Comment: Oh, [that was a defect](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2160). Only affects C++14 too.